# How to get Year from Date Report Parameter-Birt Report

Tags: java, reporting, birt

I created one birt report.It contains one report parameter with name "FromDate".User will insert it in a fromat like "dd/MM/yyyy". I want to get year(if date is 11/01/2013.i want to extract 2013 from this varaible) from this input parameter and want to pass this value to one stored procedure(ie data set).How can i do that.Can anyone pls share sample code

Comment: This question is also posted at http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/29211-how-to-get-year-from-date-report-parameter-birt-report/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this one..in corresponding stored procedure i will do a substring on input paramaeter(ie FromDate)..it is working

Comment: instead of using like this go to your report and select the corresponding cell and in property window you find Format DATE TIME and there you can customize your date as you wish.

Comment: Did you try any of the other offered answers? Note that while this method solves your underlying problem, it doesn't actually answer the question asked.

Comment: If you are still having problems, try and recreate what you want (or to show the problem) using the sample data base (Classic Cars).  Post the report to your question at birt-exchange.org it will be easier for someone to help you find the solution.

Comment: @vmb: you can accept your own answer to show, that your question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a variable 'selectedYear' like this:

```
var selectedValue = params["FromDate"].value;
var selectedValueArray = selectedValue.split("/");
selectedValueArray[2]
```

This code creates an array by "cutting up" the parameter value on the /'s, and then selecting the year (the second value in the array, which is the third block since we count from zero).

You can then use `vars["selectedYear"]` on your data set.

Alternatively, if your data set contains a list of years, you can create a data set

```
select distinct YEAR
from [dataSource]
```

and have your parameter select from that list instead. This will also guarantee that the selected year is in range.

Comment: If you define a variable '`"selectedYear"` containing the code block above, you can use it in your data set by adding a property binding (through the data set editor): `"select (what ever you like) from (the table you want) where year = " + vars["selectedYear"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can map dataset parameters to report parameter-derived values in the **Parameters** section of the **Edit Dataset** dialog:

- Select the stored procedure year input parameter from the list of dataset parameters and click `Edit...` .
- Click on the `fx` button next to the Default Value and select `Javascript Syntax` .
- Enter the formula `BirtDateTime.year(params["FromDate"].value)` .

Click on OK to confirm these changes in each dialog. (The Linked To Report Parameter option needs to be left as `None` for that dataset parameter, since you don't want to set the procedure input parameter value to be exactly the same as any of the Report Parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past, however i looked at from a different angle in driving the date selection from the dates stored in the datasource as a dynamic parameter. Normally then a date from the dataset is in a format which can be formatted/extracted by functions to give the year month day etc.

Answer (score 0):

In sql query(Data Set), Use this

"**split_part(?,'/',3)"** , We will have date parameter in place of '?' . As, you must be aware of that, Split_part will divide the string using the delimiter '/' .